# Wrong value count

Tags: c#, .net, registry

I'm trying to get all the startups programs, but I have the wrong value count.

I do this :

```
    private const int m_HKCU_PATH_CODE = 0;
    private const int m_HKLM_PATH_CODE = 1;
    private const string m_REGISTRY_PATH = @"Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Run";
```

[...]

```
        m_InitialStartupPrograms = new Dictionary<string, int>();

        m_RegistryKey = Registry.CurrentUser.OpenSubKey(m_REGISTRY_PATH);
        foreach (string startupPrograms in m_RegistryKey.GetValueNames())
            m_InitialStartupPrograms.Add(startupPrograms, m_HKCU_PATH_CODE);

        m_RegistryKey.Close();

        m_RegistryKey = Registry.LocalMachine.OpenSubKey(m_REGISTRY_PATH);
        foreach (string startupPrograms in m_RegistryKey.GetValueNames())
            m_InitialStartupPrograms.Add(startupPrograms, m_HKLM_PATH_CODE);

        m_RegistryKey.Close();
```

But I only have 11 startup programs, whereas the registry contains 14 startup programs.
In fact, all the missing statup programs are in LocalMachine. I correctly get all startup programs in CurrentUser.

EDIT : I don't really understand...

http://puu.sh/9N1pd/86ffb17fed.png

On the screen, we cans see that its the same folder but there are differnt keys ! (I accessed to the folders thanks to CCleaner.)

Comment: Is your program running as a 32 bit program on a 64 bit machine? If it is you are really looking at `Software\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Run`

Comment: Okay, so, by changing the run parameters 32 to 64 bits, I had the 3 missings startup programs. Then I had looking for at the path you said me and I had all startup programs ! Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is your program running as a 32 bit program on a 64 bit machine? If it is you are really looking at `Software\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Run`

If you are using .NET 4 or newer you can tell it which folder to check via OpenBaseKey

Here is a much cleaned up version of your program that uses it.

```
private void Init()
{
    m_InitialStartupPrograms = new Dictionary<string, int>();

    LoadDictionary(RegistryHive.LocalMachine, RegistryView.Registry32, m_HKLM_PATH_CODE);
    LoadDictionary(RegistryHive.LocalMachine, RegistryView.Registry64, m_HKLM_PATH_CODE);
    LoadDictionary(RegistryHive.CurrentUser, RegistryView.Registry32, m_HKCU_PATH_CODE);
    LoadDictionary(RegistryHive.CurrentUser, RegistryView.Registry64, m_HKCU_PATH_CODE);
}

//Instead of repeating the same code over and over, make a function then just 
// call the function repeatedly with different parameters.
private void LoadDictionary(RegistryHive hive, RegistryView view, int pathCode)
{
    //based on the name m_RegistryKey it appears that those where not local variables.
    //Because you close them right away there is no reason not to make them local
    // variables inside using statements.

    using (var baseKey = RegistryKey.OpenBaseKey(hive, view))
    using (var subKey = baseKey.OpenSubKey(m_REGISTRY_PATH))
    {
        foreach (string startupPrograms in subKey.GetValueNames())
        {
            m_InitialStartupPrograms.Add(startupPrograms, pathCode);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Just a question. Should I compile in 32 bits or 64 bits or in both architecture and leave the choice to users ? (my computer is 64 bits, but I'd like to share my soft). If it's in 32 bits and executed on 32 bits computer, is it necessary to read in Registry64 ? (I think the answer is no, but I prefer to check)

Comment: Use the "Any CPU" setting. It will do 64 on 64 bit machines and 32 on 32 bit machines.

Comment: I have done another thing. I compile in 32 bits and I check if the OS is 64 bits or 32 bits. If it's 64 bits I, read in Registry32 and Registry64. Else, I only read in Registry32. Thanks for all guy !